# spring security not eligible for auto-proxying

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

can anyone elaborate what does these info means when startup application?

```
INFO: Bean 'org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJPointcutAdvisor#0' is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
Jan 13, 2010 11:00:34 AM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext$BeanPostProcessorChecker postProcessAfterInitialization
INFO: Bean '(inner bean)#2' is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
Jan 13, 2010 11:00:34 AM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext$BeanPostProcessorChecker postProcessAfterInitialization
INFO: Bean 'org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJPointcutAdvisor#1' is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
Jan 13, 2010 11:00:34 AM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext$BeanPostProcessorChecker postProcessAfterInitialization
INFO: Bean '(inner bean)#4' is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
Jan 13, 2010 11:00:34 AM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext$BeanPostProcessorChecker postProcessAfterInitialization
INFO: Bean 'org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJPointcutAdvisor#2' is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
Jan 13, 2010 11:00:34 AM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext$BeanPostProcessorChecker postProcessAfterInitialization
INFO: Bean '(inner bean)#6' is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
Jan 13, 2010 11:00:34 AM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext$BeanPostProcessorChecker postProcessAfterInitialization
INFO: Bean 'org
```

ref: http://bamboo.ci.codehaus.org/build/viewBuildLog.action;jsessionid=85C63FD38CA3A5320AE8CECE84D570B8?buildNumber=3&buildKey=MODFORJ-ROSASBREAKFAST

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a fairly normal message. A `BeanPostProcessor` is a Spring construct for altering/wrapping/proxying beans in the context. Because of the way the context lifecycle works, some things have to be configured *before* the `BeanPostProcessor` get a look in, which leads to that message.

It's almost never anything to worry about, hence the INFO level. The components that trigger the message are usually Spring's own internal components.

Comment: It would be easier if there was a way to tell which (among many) beans require being processed by `BeanPostProcessors` and which don't. Ideally, those who require should scream with `WARN` and those which don't should shut up with `DEBUG`. They are ignorable until things break and every noize becomes suspicious.